# $.each duplicates 10 twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I have #sp-pocetna10 and #sp-pocetna1, script add #sp-pocetna10 after #sp-pocetna1 and at the end too.
[image: result]

These are ID of sections on one-page website, so I need to add class active on current section or viewport ( full screen all sections ).

If I add `#sp-pocetna0`, it will duplicate right before `#sp-pocetna1`.

Do you have any idea how can I remove that duplicated sections?

```
var slidnum = jQuery("div[id^='sp-pocetna']").length + 1;
console.log("Total Scrolls: "+slidnum);
jQuery(window).on('load resize scroll', function() {

  for (i = 1; i < slidnum; i++) { 
    var strane = jQuery( "div[id^='sp-pocetna"+ i +"']" );
      strane.each(function() {
      console.log(this);
        if (jQuery(this).isInViewport()) {
          jQuery("#sp-dots .custom li:nth-child("+ i +") a").addClass("active");
          //console.log("Jeste u VP:"+str);
        } else {
          jQuery("#sp-dots .custom li:nth-child("+ i +") a").removeClass("active");
          //console.log("Nije u VP:"+str);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: I think that "duplicated" section is already there in your HTML markup; as a matter of facts yout script does not alter the html structure, it just iterates elements.

Comment: I am using Joomla, and i built template for it. So, there is no duplicated sections. 

http://prntscr.com/o6hezo

Comment: By the way, you are already iterating through your elements using a `for` loop, why are you also using `.each`?

Comment: ah, you're missing the zeroth element: `for (i=0; i < slidenum; i++)`

Comment: To get `#sp-pocetna[number]` and to add for this `jQuery("#sp-dots .custom li:nth-child("+ i +") a").addClass("active");`

Comment: equals `jQuery("div[id^='sp-pocetna']")[i]`

Comment: Instead of removing it (you don't know which one is "good" and you can have other problems in the future when you have more elements)), it's better to correct the generation script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is another place where you should rather use [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) instead of listening to scroll events. Scroll events are bad for performance and IO was built to handle cases like yours.

First you have to create a new observer:

```
var options = {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 1.0
 }

var observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, options);
```

Here we specify that once the observed element is 100% visible, some callback should be executed. If you want the callback to be executed if an element is passing 50% visible, change `threshold: .5` (or any other number you like)

Then you have to specify which items to observe, in your case I think this would be:

```
var target = document.querySelector('[id^=sp-pocenta]');
observer.observe(target);
```

With this selector you watch every element whose id start with `sp-pocenta`. 
So we define that once any element that matches this selector is visible on the page, the callback (that was defined earlier) is getting executed:

```
var callback = function(entries, observer) { 
  entries.forEach(entry => {
  // Each entry describes an intersection change for one observed
  // target element:
  });
};
```

Here you specify what should happen for each "sp-pocenta"-Element in your page that is getting visible.

Edit: If you need to support older browsers than use this [(official) polyfill from w3c](https://github.com/w3c/IntersectionObserver/tree/master/polyfill), it recreates intersection observer with listening to scroll events.

Comment: All right, I will try this. But, there is no other way?

Comment: there is only IO and listening to scroll event, that are all the options you have.